# Personal statement for exchange program

Tags: meaning-in-context

I'll apply for exchange program and i need write reasons for applying and I'm not native speaker. So I would like as that is there any mistake in my personal statement or is it understandable?

"My main reason for participating in a student exchange is to experience my profession and  to upgrade my skills by using maximum opportunities within different distant education. Since METU listed among the top 200 universities in Engineering and Technology, it will help me to expand my knowledge in IT field. Also I would like to get familiar with world education system and gain life experience."

Comment: Welcome to EL&U. We are neither a proofreading service nor a writers workshop, though we can help you work through specific points of grammar or usage that confuse you. Please take the [site tour](http://english.stackexchange.com/tour) and review the [help center](http://english.stackexchange.com/help) for additional guidance on how to use this site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would change it to this:

"My main reason for participating in a student exchange program is to have an experience that would be a huge aid towards my profession. Also, I believe a student exchange program could upgrade my skills through the many opportunities that would be provided. Since METU is listed among the top 200 universities in Engineering and Technology, it will help me to expand my knowledge in the IT field. Moreover, I would like to acquire more information about the different world education systems. Lastly, this student exchange program will allow me to gain experience in life and play a crucial role in improving the person in which I have become."

This is just to my taste. I'm not sure what you meant by "by using maximum opportunities within different distant education," but hopefully, I got the idea!! :D

Comment: Proofreading is off-topic for EL&U.